# MySQL select query using 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, join

My following query shows results only if dcno is exists in dc_detail table
but what i actually need is even then if dcno is not exists in dc_detail table it should define dcno as `0` and select that results also
Thanks in advance

```
SELECT p.po_no as id, DATE_FORMAT(p.po_date, '%d-%m-%Y')as po_date, p.customer, p.cust_po as po_no,p.tot_ord_qty,
DATE_FORMAT(p.delivery_date, '%d-%m-%Y')as delivery_date,p.dc_status,p.inv_status,p.tot_dc_qty,p.tot_inv_qty,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct d.dc_no SEPARATOR ', ') as dc FROM po_header p, dc_details d  
where p.cust_po=d.cust_po  
group by p.cust_po;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use left join to include headers that have no details. That will give you rows with nulls for the detail fields that don't exist.
To get the value 0 instead of null you can use coalesce function.
The relevant parts of the query are

```
SELECT COALESCE(d.dc_no, 0),...
FROM po_header p LEFT JOIN dc_detail d ON p.cust_po=d.cust_po
```

Coalesce function returns the first non null argument.